# How to scrape a text when it'ss not in a HTML element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, data-mining

I want to scrape this website: https://www.hectorjones.co.nz/milwaukee-hand-tools-and-accessories.html
I want to scrape Product Sku, Price, List Price elements.
I had manage to scrape Price but I have problems with other two, especially Product Sku because it is not in span. It's just in a div, is it possible to scrape it? if so can you help me

as you see the Product Sku has no span.

```
<div class="vm3pr-2"> <div class="product-price" id="productPrice1499">
<div class="product-sku"><span class="bold">Product SKU</span> : 2203-20<br></div>
```

here is the more of the code.

```
<div class="vm3pr-2"> <div class="product-price" id="productPrice1499">
<div class="product-sku"><span class="bold">Product SKU</span> : 2203-20<br></div>
<div class="PricesalesPrice vm-display vm-price-value"><span class="vm-price-desc">Price (inc GST): 
</span><span class="PricesalesPrice">$45.00</span></div><span class="ex-tax"></span><div 
class="PricediscountAmount vm-nodisplay"><span class="vm-price-desc">Discount: </span><span 
class="PricediscountAmount"></span></div></div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

and here is my code

```
    prices = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("PricesalesPrice")
    sku = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("bold")
    list_price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("PricebasePriceWithTax")

    for price in prices:
        print(price.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Burak previously written code was in django. As you asked, here is the code just you have to run in cmd and it will print the list of products available in that website.

First make sure to install these two python packages:

**pip install requests**

**pip install bs4**

***scraping.py***

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.hectorjones.co.nz/milwaukee-hand-tools-and-accessories.html'


response = requests.get(base_url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')
post_listings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-price'})
final_postings = []

for post in post_listings:
    product_sku = post.find('div', {'class': 'product-sku'}).text
    price = post.find('span', {'class': 'PricesalesPrice'}).text
    final_postings.append((product_sku, price))

print(final_postings)
```

Let me know if you confused in any steps.
Happy coding

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you

Comment: By the way any ideas how can I script the List Price ( it only appears in some of the items) is it possible to script that too? It throws an error when I try to do that in the for loop you built since not every item has List Price.

Comment: I didn't get what you told about script

Comment: Some items have List Price too.
https://ibb.co/y4rg34C

is it scrapable?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can do this to get products-sku with respective price. I am using beautiful soup for scraping....

**views.py**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from django.shortcuts import render

base_url = 'https://www.hectorjones.co.nz/milwaukee-hand-tools-and-accessories.html'


def home(request):
    response = requests.get(base_url)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')
    post_listings = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-price'})
    final_postings = []

    for post in post_listings:
        product_sku = post.find('div', {'class': 'product-sku'}).text
        price = post.find('span', {'class': 'PricesalesPrice'}).text
        final_postings.append((product_sku, price))
    context = {
        'final_postings': final_postings,
       }

    return render(request, 'display.html', context)
```

**display.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>hectorjones.co.nz/</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for post in final_postings %}
    <ul>
         <li><p>{{ post.0 }}<br> Price : {{ post.1 }}
         </p></li>
    </ul>

{% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Shiva.
This is not a format I am used to.
Should just put these 2 files in same directory and then open cmd and type "python views.py"?
Would that make it?

Comment: I know its related to django but is there any easier way to make it work? thanks.
@shiva-shrestha any help would be very useful